# pyvisa controlling Keithley_2750_DMM

Tags: python-3.x, pyvisa

I am using Keithley_2750_DMM to measure the 4 wire resistance with 6 channels  ,with 6 sample count

when i am trying to read the values ,but it is  showing errors ,
does anybody wrote code in python to measure the 4 wire resistance,
apparently the error comes out when I try to query any value for example print(inst.query(':READ?'), I tried get the device detail and it works "*IDN?"

the code i am trying is

import pyvisa

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()

inst = rm.open_resource('ASRL1::INSTR')

print(inst.query("*IDN?"))

inst.write("STAT:QUE:CLE")

inst.write("TRAC:CLE.")

inst.write(":FUNC "FRES" , (@101:106).;:FRES:RANG:AUTO ON")

inst.write("(@101:106).;:FRES:DIG 7 , (@101:106)")

inst.write(":FRES:OCOM ON , (@101:106)")

inst.write(":FRES:DCIR ON , (@101:106)")

inst.write("ROUT:SCAN (@101:106)")

inst.write("ROUT:SCAN:LSEL INT.;SAMP:COUN 6")

inst.write("FORM:ELEM READ.;READ?")

print(inst.query(':READ?')

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have many errors.

```
import pyvisa

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()    
inst = rm.open_resource('ASRL1::INSTR')

print(inst.query("*IDN?"))    
inst.write("STAT:QUE:CLE")    # i recommend using "*RST" here instead
inst.write("TRAC:CLE.")   # "." will cuase a syntax error
inst.write(":FUNC "FRES" , (@101:106).;:FRES:RANG:AUTO ON")    # Double set of quations. change inner quotations.    
inst.write("(@101:106).;:FRES:DIG 7 , (@101:106)")    # unclear. looks like a copy paste error from somewhere else.
inst.write(":FRES:OCOM ON , (@101:106)")    
inst.write(":FRES:DCIR ON , (@101:106)")    
inst.write("ROUT:SCAN (@101:106)")    
inst.write("ROUT:SCAN:LSEL INT.;SAMP:COUN 6")  # "." will cuase a syntax error  
inst.write("FORM:ELEM READ.;READ?")    # can't leave a hanging query
print(inst.query(':READ?')
```

My suggestion below. **Copying and pasting will not work**, look at what I've changes and you'll need to fit that with what you are trying to do.

```
import pyvisa

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()    
inst = rm.open_resource('ASRL1::INSTR')

print(inst.query("*IDN?"))    
inst.write("*RST")
inst.write(":FUNC 'FRES', (@101:106);:FRES:RANG:AUTO ON")
inst.write(":FRES:DIG 7, (@101:106)")
inst.write(":FRES:OCOM ON, (@101:106)")    
inst.write(":FRES:DCIR ON, (@101:106)")    
inst.write(":ROUT:SCAN (@101:106)")    
inst.write("ROUT:SCAN:LSEL INT;:SAMP:COUN 6")
print(inst.query("FORM:ELEM READ;READ?")
```

To help you work out where the errors are add an error query after each write. like this:

```
inst.write(":FRES:DIG 7, (@101:106)")
print(inst.query("SYSTem:ERRor?")
inst.write(":FRES:OCOM ON, (@101:106)")  
print(inst.query("SYSTem:ERRor?")  
inst.write(":FRES:DCIR ON, (@101:106)")    
print(inst.query("SYSTem:ERRor?")
```

Comment: thank you , i just ad timeout and it worked